# TSQL Dynamic Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a Dynamic TSQL query that is working for the most part however I am now trying to add an `IN` clause to it as I am passing multiple employee ID's and want to get their data.

This is what my statement looks like for the  piece I am adding:

```
IF @awardEmployees IS NOT NULL
        SET @Where = @Where + ' AND A.[employee] IN 'SELECT ParamValues.x2.value('empID[1]', 'VARCHAR(60)') FROM  @awardEmployees.nodes('/employees/employee') AS ParamValues(x2);
```

Is it possible to have an IN clause in a dynamic query like this? I have been trying what I could but nothing seems to work. All its currently doing is returning the `empID` I am searching, not even running the query correctly.

UPDATE:

When I did it like so, it worked for a single employee:

```
IF @awardEmployees IS NOT NULL
        SET @Where = @Where + ' AND A.[employee] IN (''' +(SELECT ParamValues.x2.value('empID[1]', 'VARCHAR(60)') FROM @awardEmployees.nodes('/employees/employee') AS ParamValues(x2)) + ''')';
```

However, When my XML contains 2 employes or more, it throws this error:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Comment: Your subquery must return a string, or something implicitly convertible to a string such as a single-column single-row rowset. In the case of many values, they have to be concatenated together and separated by commas to become a single string! When your subquery returns a result such as `1,2,15,27`, then you'll be ready to add it to the dynamic SQL string.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not too sure how to convert the XML input to a string. I have always done it that way but it doesnt seem to work in the case of this dynamic query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the table returned by the nodes() method to a comma separated list of values.

```
        IF @awardEmployees IS NOT NULL
             SET @Where = @Where + ' AND A.[employee] IN (' + stuff(
          (
            select ','+QUOTENAME(ParamValues.x2.value('@empID[1]', 'VARCHAR(60)'), '''')
            FROM @awardEmployees.nodes('/employees/employee') AS ParamValues(x2)
            for xml path(''),type
          ).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,1,'') + ')'
```

The following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f155e/1) demonstrates the idea. BTW when you do so, you will not need the parameter for the `@_awardEmployees = @awardEmployees` in your sp_executesql call

Comment: This worked great ; thanks a lot. The one issue I have is trying to set the value to null when I have no employees to look up. 
`SET @awardEmployees = NULLIF(@awardEmployees, '')` this doesnt work as I get the error `The data types xml and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.` Is there a way to set this as null when the value passed is empty?

Comment: Just remove this line. Your if statement is checking for null

Comment: Right but the script passes something regardless, it with either been an XML string or an empty value. So it will always be something other than null which is why I have the other lines that say if '' then it's null

Answer (score 0):

You need parentheses for the `in` and around the subquery:

```
IF @awardEmployees IS NOT NULL
    SET @Where = @Where + ' AND A.[employee] IN (''' +
                 (SELECT ParamValues.x2.value('empID[1]', 'VARCHAR(60)') FROM @awardEmployees.nodes('/employees/employee') AS ParamValues(x2)
                 ) + ''');
```

This assumes that the result of the query is a single row with a single column that has a comma delimited list.

EDIT:

You might try concatenating them together:

```
IF @awardEmployees IS NOT NULL
    SET @Where = @Where + ' AND A.[employee] IN (' +
                 stuff((SELECT ', ''' + ParamValues.x2.value('empID[1]', 'VARCHAR(60)') + ''''
                        FROM @awardEmployees.nodes('/employees/employee') AS ParamValues(x2)
                        FOR XML PATH ('')
                       ), 1, 2, '') + ');
```

Comment: I tried something like this and got an error when running it `SQL Server]Invalid column name 'ABC123'` < thats the employee ID I was searching. I tried it exactly and got that same error

Comment: @SBB . . . In that case, you need more single quotes, as I just added.

Comment: You should edit your question and show what the `@where` variable has after variable substitution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I think you will need to construct a comma-separated list from the `SELECT ParamValues.x2.value`. I think you will need to use a FOR XML PATH or some other method

Comment: This is what my whole SP looks like. I am trying to figure out how to show the where clause before executing : http://pastebin.com/JWd8aLkZ

Comment: use `PRINT @SQL` to view the SQL statement before executing

Comment: Can you post an example of `@awardEmployees` XML data